# Using sqlalchemy session to execute sql DRASTICALLY slows execution time

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a rather long query (was 7 joins, now is 7 subselects because in raw sql 7 subselects was considerably faster-- I don't even know when the 7 joins would have finished if I'd let it run, but longer than 1 min versus .05-.1 seconds with subselects)

When I run it on the db it takes, as I said, .05-.1 seconds to execute. Simply using `session.execute()` slows it down to over a minute!

Is there anything I can do?

Let me know if you need more info-- I kind of suspect this is a general sqlalchemy thing-- like maybe sqlalchemy is setting up a query plan instead of just letting mysql do it? Or...?

EDIT: ran explain on both and they seem identical except that sqlalchemy adds a "using temporary; using filesort" to the `extra` column. Is that what's slowing it down? How do I stop it from doing that?

EDIT 2: DEFINITELY sqlalchemy. I tried using a MySQL cursor to execute instead of an SA session and got the same .05 second runtime.

EDIT 3:

The code to create our engine:

```
engine_ro = create_engine(
    config.ro_database_url, #string with username, password, db
    pool_size=config.database_pool_size, #int
    max_overflow=config.database_max_overflow, #int
    pool_timeout=config.database_timeout, # int
    echo=config.database_echo, #False
    echo_pool=config.database_echo, #same as echo #False
    listeners=[GoneAway()] if config.database_use_listeners else None)
```

where `GoneAway()` is a method that executes a `SELECT 1` to check the connection.

To create the session object:

```
SessionRO = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine_ro, autocommit=False))
```

where `scoped_session` and `sessionmaker` are sqlalchemy functions.

Then, the code that executes the query:

```
session = SessionRO()
results = session.execute(sql, params)
```

EDIT 4: In case anyone is wondering, if I comment out the `listeners` bit, it's still slow. As well if I just use `sessionmaker` without scoped_session.

Comment: `sqlalchemy` doesn't set up a query plan, or anything else fancy. It just generates SQL and sends it over a DB-API-2.0 connection. You can see exactly what SQL it generates in various ways, but the easiest is to pass `echo=True` as an extra param on the `create_engine` call.

Comment: And you probably want to look at the SQL for differences first, and only then the EXPLAIN and/or EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN differences.

Comment: Or there may be a quick fix that makes your problem irrelevant: Turn your long query (or a sizable chunk of it) into a VIEW, then do a simple query against that VIEW. (That may also allow MySQL to optimize the lookup better in the first place, if you're lucky.)

Comment: The query is the same, to your second point. I'm actually right at this moment being tasked with this because we were using views and they were very slow, so I don't think turning it back into a view would help. It seems that sqlalchemy is playing *some* part in the query plan, because as I said, the extra column is different when I run explain in and out of sqlalchemy.

Comment: I can't imagine how a view could be _slower_ than the exact same query run separately. (I _can_ imagine how a join could be slower than a subselect… but you can turn the subselect query into a view just as easily as a join.) And if I found such a case, I'd report it as a bug.

Comment: From what I've heard from a coworker who did the research (though I didn't do it myself) filters don't propogate through subselects in views, so it actually CAN be slower.

Comment: Meanwhile, if the query is the same, but it's evaluated differently (consistently), there's obviously something else different about the connection parameters, pragmas, etc. that causes that difference. And I'd start there; instead of trying to guess all the top-level differences that could cause a given low-level difference, look at the top-level difference and the low-level difference and verify that they match up.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. I'm hoping it's a sqlalchemy config somewhere, but what would the value be?

Comment: Well, you can always record any pragmas or other SQL strings that get sent. As for capturing the connection parameters, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do that, but if not… you could always monkeypatch either `sqlalchemy` or the MySQL library to log that, or just put a breakpoint there and run int he debugger, right?

Comment: session.execute(), as far as the interaction with the string you send and with how the DBAPI is used, is very basic.  There is no emission of anything like "using temporary/filesort" or anything like that, at the very least it would be the MySQL-python DBAPI doing it.   You need to illustrate for us here (or on the mailing list) exactly how you create your `Engine`, your `Session`, and how you are calling `execute()` on it, versus what you did when you tested a plain MySQL cursor.   The SQL itself would help too but just the calling style here would be of help in diagnosing.

Comment: @zzzeek included the engine, session, and execute code.

Comment: @abarnert you were right-- the queries *weren't* the same. If you post an answer maybe I can reassign answer credit? (sorry, did it before I thought to tell you. If not I will at least upvote you...)

Comment: @Colleen: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlalchemy` doesn't set up a query plan, or anything else fancy. It just generates SQL and sends it over a DB-API-2.0 connection. So, if you explicitly call `execute` with the same statement that `sqlalchemy` generates, it will run in exactly the same way.*

The simplest way to see what queries `sqlalchemy` is generating is to pass `echo=True` as an extra param on the `create_engine` call.

In your case, the query generated by `sqlalchemy` was in fact different from your manual query, because it was testing an integer parameter with a string, instead of with an int.

---

* This isn't 100% guaranteed; you have to make sure that any connection parameters in the DB-API-2.0 `connect` function are the same, and that neither you nor `sqlalchemy` executed any `PRAGMA` statements. But you can test those in much the same way you can test the query itself.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a real test suite to compare MySQL cursor with SQLAlchemy engine and session.   Please substitute your connection information and SQL at the bottom, then run it.  Let us know what the timings are.

```
import time

def time_thing(fn, description):
    print "Running %s" % description
    now = time.time()
    try:
        ret = fn()
        return ret
    finally:
        spent = time.time() - now
        print "Finished %s, took %d seconds" % (description, spent)

def with_mysqldb(sql):
    import MySQLdb

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(db=DBNAME, user=USERNAME, passwd=PASSWORD, host=HOST)

    def go():
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)

        # if result fetching is the issue:
        # cursor.fetchall()

        cursor.close()

    time_thing(go, "Executing SQL with MySQLdb cursor")

def _sqla_engine_w_test_connection():
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    eng = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_URL)

    def test():
        conn = eng.connect()
        result = conn.execute("select 1")
        assert result.fetchall()[0] == (1, )

    time_thing(test, "Making a test connection...")

    return eng

def with_sqlalchemy(sql):
    eng = _sqla_engine_w_test_connection()

    def go():
        result = eng.execute(sql)

        # if result fetching is the issue:
        # result.fetchall()

        result.close()
    time_thing(go, "Executing SQL with SQLA engine")

def with_sqlalchemy_session(sql):
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

    eng = _sqla_engine_w_test_connection()

    def go():
        sess = Session(eng)

        result = sess.execute(sql)

        # if result fetching is the issue:
        # result.fetchall()

        result.close()

    time_thing(go, "Executing SQL SQLA session")

SQLALCHEMY_URL = "mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test"
DBNAME = "test"
HOST = "localhost"
USERNAME = "scott"
PASSWORD = "tiger"
SQL = "SELECT 1"

with_mysqldb(SQL)
with_sqlalchemy(SQL)
with_sqlalchemy_session(SQL)
```

Comment: This has only served to confuse me more, as it proves everyone's point (they all take within 2 seconds of each other), but seriously, if I copy and paste the mysql connection code into mine and run it within my full context (webserver hitting a rest api which hits the db), it returns instantly. Even with fetchall() and iterating over things. WHAT IS DIFFERENT?!!!!!

Comment: Giving you answer credit because you proved to me it was me, even though nobody found the actual problem, which I'll post about.

Comment: edit: giving answer credit to abarnert because they had the actual answer but giving you the bounty because you put in a lot of effort that helped me actually realize what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Which DBAPI are you using? Maybe try to change it to something else. I'm working with PostgreSQL now and I experience big difference in performance between pypostgresql and psycopg2 (latter one is much faster).

For a list of available DBAPIs for MySQL refer to SQLAchemy documentation: chapter 4.1.5.

Comment: link? I see no obvious chapter numbers in the sqlalchemy documentation, just a topic list, and searching the index only yeilds db api *error* stuff. edit: nvm, found it. But yeah, don't see a chapter number on here anywhere, so in the future a link would be helpful

Comment: Also, to answer your question: we're... not using any? Our connection strings are just "mysql://<stuff>"

Answer (score 0):

In the console version, I was pasting the right thing.
In the SqlAlchemy version, I was testing against **an int parameter with a string**.